# python subprocess and wget ask-password

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running the following python code:

```
import subprocess
host = "ftp://localhost:2121"
p = subprocess.Popen(
  ['wget', '-P', '/tmp/output', '-N', '-r', '-l', 'inf', '--ask-password', '--user', 'anonymous', host],
  stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate("password\n")
if p.returncode != 0:
    raise RuntimeError('wget command failed with return code: %d' % p.returncode)
```

It appears that `password` is not sent to wget since the script will hang showing:

```
Password for user ‘anonymous’:
```

Pressing enter causes wget to exit with an error code of '1'

Pressing keys then pressing enter causes wget to begin downloading as expected.

The ftp server is local and has anonymous access enabled. Python version is 2.7.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that wget reads the password from the tty rather than stdin. These are not the same!

The sudo command allows you to [switch to stdin](https://askubuntu.com/a/322640)

[also](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328313/pass-password-to-a-script-running-over-ssh/328318#328318)

> Certain programs read directly from /dev/tty, not stdin. "passwd" for example. So it's difficult to script them. Expect is one way around that - it can trick the program by providing input to them:

One way to achieve reading the password from stdin is to construct a url containing the user & pass:

`ftp://user:password@ftp.server.com/link.txt`

And using the `-l -` switch to pass the link into wget via stdin. This is suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29079/how-do-i-provide-a-username-and-password-to-wget#comment1672739_399927)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before `p.communicate`:

```
p.stdin.write('password\n')
p.stdin.flush()
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Comment: No luck :( wget wouldn't be doing something like spinning up a different process to request the password, would it?

Comment: I tested it and indeed you're right... this is interesting. Can you just pass the password as an argument or is there a reason you're doing it this way?